# Changing view order in the program

Tags: android

My `main.xml` has `ListView` and `ImageView`. Now `ListView` is behind the `ImageView`. How can I make when the user touch the screen, the `ImageView` is put behind the `ListView`. How can I implement in the program? My `main.xml` is as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tracker_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/im1" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is listView in this xml? there are only linearlayouts and imageview

Comment: No I have another xml for list fragment.

Comment: then include it so we can help

Answer (score 0):

You can try bring the list view to the top by using

```
listView.bringToFront()
```

Comment: So I need to detect that the user touches to the screen. Then call listView.bringToFront(). Let me test.